# Modify test names based on command line parameters

Tags: python, appium, pytest, python-appium

I am using pytest to run appium tests with python-appium.

I run the tests on different devices, and I use a command line parameter to select the device via `pytest_addoption`.

I output the test results via `--junitxml`. Afterwards I collect the test results in jenkins.

It would be really useful if the test names would be prefixed with the platform name.

How can this be done in py.test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to modify a test name is to add a parameter to a fixture.

So now I do:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", params= pytest.devices)
def env():
    ...
```

and in my conftest.py:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--device", action="store",
        help="the device to use")

def pytest_configure(config):
    pytest.devices = [config.getoption('--device')]
```